# Can a json file contain a key in the nth element that is not in preceding elements?

Tags: python, json, pandas, io

Is this a legitimate json structure?  How would I access subDictkey at an arbitrary point in someList?  (e.g. not someList[4]['someList'])  Must 'subDictkey' exist in every element of 'someList'?

```
{ 
    'dict': {
        'someList': [
           {},
           {},
           {},
           {},
           {'subDictkey':
                'sublist':[]
           },
        ]
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I'll take silence to mean this would be terrible and you shouldn't do it.

I would assume that elements should be should be consistent throughout the list and not just 'appear' in the nth element.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the original question.

Comment: well, no I suppose not, but it is my question.  Sometimes no answer is the answer.  If you have a better one I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the list `sublist` this works good:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

js = """[{ 
    "dict": {
        "someList": [
           {"a":1},
           {"b":2},
           {"subDictkey": 
             {"sublist": 
               ["a","b","c"]
             }
           }
        ]
    }
 }]""";


with open('a.json','w') as fo:
  fo.write(js)

## read json file
with open('a.json') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data=data,meta=[['dict', 'somelist','subDictkey']])
df.values[0][0][2]['subDictkey']['sublist']

Gives:
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: What I should be able to do is return a df where all the fields are 1d, and I have only the meta data that I need.  Here I can get the specific field, but not without knowing in advance where it is, and doing extra work on the df to remove superfluous data.